# My Navigation Bar Doesn't Work... Need help. Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

need your help. I am trying to create a collapsing navigation bar for our project website in school. Since I am just starting to learn bootstrap, I can not see what have I done wrongfully.
Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Viking's Pawnshop</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right: 20px">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="slide_cont">

                    <div class="slide">

                        <div class="1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="3">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="arrows">
                        <img src="../images/left.png" id="lft">
                        <img src="../images/right.png" id="ryt">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="text-align: justify;">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: “doesn’t work” is not a problem description.

Comment: Did you forget to include jquery and bootstrap.js?

Answer (score 0):

> Requires JavaScript plugin

Check the Documentation: [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

You need to include both jQuery and (at the least) the [collapse.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/collapse.js) plugin or the full [bootstrap.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/dist/js) for your collapsing nav to function. See [What's Included](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included)

> jQuery required Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery
>   to be included, as shown in the starter template. Consult our
>   bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

**Also.**

1. `align` is deprecated, see [W3C Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2).
2. Since you're placing the nav inside of a container, you can use `container-fluid` inside the `navbar` so there isn't any overflow on the `navbar-right` links. See this [Example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/).
3. You're missing the `.navbar-header` class.

Working Example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Viking's Pawnshop</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="slide_cont">
        <div class="slide">
          <div class="1">
          </div>
          <div class="2">
          </div>
          <div class="3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="arrows">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" id="lft">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" id="ryt">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
      recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
      recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
      recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're welcome and don't forget to mark you questions as answered (if they are) so others can benefit from them.